# Intuitive motivation for the $\diamondsuit$-principle?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I'm having difficulty internalizing the $\diamondsuit$-principle. I understand what it says, and can see why some of the constructions that I've seen that use it work. But I don't think I understand it well enough to know when/how to use it more generally.

Is there any "intuitive" motivating idea behind $\diamondsuit$? Or is it just an arcane principle that I'll need to learn to work with on its own terms?

Comment: What is the principle?

Comment: It is a reflection principle. Are you familiar with examples of reflection principles? With the version of reflection provable in ZFC?

Comment: There exists a sequence $\langle A_\alpha\mid \alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ such that each $A_\alpha\subseteq\alpha$ and for any $A\subseteq\omega_1$, the set $\{\alpha\mid A\cap\alpha=A_\alpha\}$ is stationary in $\omega_1$

Comment: I'm familiar with something I learned as "Montague's reflection theorem", yes. But I don't see the connection

Comment: $\Diamond$, in simple terms, provides a witness that guesses initial segments of any subset of $\omega_{1}$ correctly on stationary many heights. This can be viewed as a sort of 'uniform choice principle' which allows for neat constructions, since we have some additional control over future stages, without having them constructed yet. Look at some of the classical constructions using $\Diamond$ to get a better idea of what I'm talking about (e.g. construct a Souslin tree from $\Diamond$). It may also be a good idea to look at Jensen's handwritten notes.